# How can other users use my GCM application?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed a GCM application, where a server app sends notification to the Android app via GCM. Now I want to offer this application to users, but how do I deal with the `SENDER_ID` and **API Key**.

How can I let users use my application, do I let them use my `SENDER_ID` and API Key or how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want individual devices to send out GCM messages. As an alternative, have your devices send a message to your server saying that a GCM message should be sent.

The benefits to doing this are many:

- You won't have to deploy the GCM server JAR with your Android app.
- No messy management for passing the Sender ID or API key to devices.
- You can use the white list of IP addresses allowed to post GCM messages in the console (the alternative would require you to have this wide open).
- Devices won't need to handle the `MulticastResult` object and update registration IDs (sounds like something you only want done server side).

Comment: This is a security application, I don't think users would like that. That is an absolute no-go. +1 for the pros of this decision anyway.

Comment: Can you explain the alternative? Why don't I want individuals sending out GCM messages?

Comment: Both of those questions should be answered already, I gave 4 reasons why having devices send out GCM messages is terrible. The alternative is have your devices request that your server send the GCM messages (i.e. the device posts over HTTP what the message contents should be, and who are the recipients, and the server relays to Google's servers).

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to offer this GCM service, every user should be able to set this up all by himself. In the former case I would be responsible for maintenance etc. I don't want this. Is the only alternative to managing a central message hub, to give my Sender ID and API Key away to the public? Is that harmful?